# My profile picture doesn't show in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, profile-picture

I'm learning to create some forum, but when I update a photo profile, it can't show. When I try to inspect element it says:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

This is my Controller:

```
public function update()
{
    $avatar = request()->file('avatar');
    $avatar_validate = 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048';

    request()->validate([
        'username' => 'required|alpha_num|min:6|max:20|unique:users,username,' . auth()->id(),
        'name' => 'string|required',
        'avatar' => $avatar ? $avatar_validate : "",
    ]);

    $hash = auth()->user()->hash;

    $avatar_name = $avatar->storeAs('profile-picture', "{$hash}.{$avatar->extension()}");

    auth()->user()->update([
        'username' => request('username'),
        'name' => request('name'),
        'avatar' => $avatar_name,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('users.show', auth()->user()->usernameOrHash());
}
```

Comment: You can't use functions inside of quotes. `"{$hash}.{$avatar->extension()}"` will not create the filename you expect. You'll have to break out of the quotes and concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$hash = auth()->user()->hash;

$filename = $hash . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

$avatar_name = $avatar->storeAs('profile-picture', $filename);
```

Also maybe you have some "trash" files stored with a weird filename in your "profile-picture" directory

Comment: Is there a point to including `use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;`? I don't see it referenced in the original code or your answer.

Comment: You're right, im going to edit my answer, it surelly is already included in OP's code otherwise he would get another exception.

Comment: What error would they get? You don't need to include the class to reference functions (like `getClientOriginalExtension`) of an already existing instance (`$avatar`). You only really need that line if you're creating a new instance or accessing static methods, like `new UploadedFile()`, or `UploadedFile::example()`.

Comment: You're right once again mr Tim, it's already a file object instance as per the Laravel manual "The file method returns an instance of the Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile class" thanks for the heads up !

Comment: Haha no worries :) And yeah, it was just a sidenote; including it wouldn't really have any adverse affects, and the rest of your answer seems correct!

Comment: maybe `$hash .'.'. $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension()` to include the '.' before the extension

Comment: or maybe i'm wrong when i call it in show.blade.php? `<img width="40" height="40" src="{{ asset($thread->user->avatar()) }}" class="mr-3 rounded-circle" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: center;" alt="...">`